# Displaying Bar chart in different window

Tags: struts2

I am trying to display a bar chart on click of button on a page which is `test.jsp`. I am able to display the chart,but it opens as a image in the same browser where my `test.jsp` is.I want to display it in a new Window ,how can I do that. I am using Struts2 and Jfreechart:

Following is my action :

```java
public class TestAction  extends ActionSupport{

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        //code to populate DataSet

        chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
               "Bar Chart",     //Chart title
            "",     //Domain axis label
            "MARKETS",         //Range axis label
            dataSet,         //Chart Data 
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
            true,             // include legend?
            true,             // include tooltips?
            false             // include URLs?
        );
     chart.setBorderVisible(true);
     return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Following is my `struts.xml` :

```xml
<action name="testAction" 
        class="testAction" 
        method="execute">
             <result name="success" type="chart">
                <param name="value">chart</param>
                <param name="type">jpeg</param>
                <param name="width">600</param>
                <param name="height">400</param>
            </result> 
</action>

<action name="displayDataAction" 
        class="testAction" 
        method="getData">
            <result name="success">test.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Jsp is :

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Data</title>
<s:head theme="ajax" debug="true"/>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

<s:form validate="true" target="_blank">
<table>

//Mapping of data from database

</table>

<s:submit id="submit" value="Display Chart" align="left" action="testAction"/>
<s:submit value="Display Data" align="left" action="displayDataAction"/>`
  </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is your action called? using jquery/js or jsp? Can you paste code?

Comment: Hi Almas,Action is getting called from test.jsp as follows :<s:submit id="submit" value="Display Chart" align="left" action="testAction"/>

Comment: change your s:form to form like this <form action="blah blah" target="_blank">

Comment: Super cool...worked perfectly...Thank you so much.

Comment: But there is one problem.....I have another button on a page..on click of which  i want to display data on same page..but now on click of that button also it is opening a new window

Comment: I have added in the suggestion as an answer so it would help others in future.

Comment: can u please let me know how i can avoid the issue i am facing on click of 2nd button as mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: is that button on same form or you using jquery's onclick? Also paste your form code..

Comment: yes ...button is on same form.I have edited code in original post.Please check.

Comment: Hi Almas...do u have any idea

Comment: do you want to raise a new question for the same? As this is a follow up question really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using s:form tag and s:submit, use form tag like:

```
<form action="blah blah" target="_blank">
```

And that should resolve the issue.